# problem to import to_categorical in from keras.utils

Tags: keras, label

Solution:

instead of:
from keras.utils import to_categorical

use this:
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not asking anything. It's just a note for anyone who is facing trouble importing 'to_categorical' from Keras.